# openCV VideoCapture doesn't work with gstreamer x264

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, h.264, x264, mpeg-4

I'd like to display a rtp / vp8 video stream that comes from gstreamer, in openCV.

I have already a working solution which is implemented like this :

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=6666 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)VP8-DRAFT-IETF-01,payload=(int)120" ! rtpvp8depay ! vp8dec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! filesink location=videoStream
```

Basically it grabs incoming data from a UDP socket, depacketize rtp, decode vp8, pass to ffmpegcolorspace (I still don't understand what this is for, I see it everywhere in gstreamer).

The `videoStream` is a pipe I created with `mkfifo`. On the side, I have my openCV code that does :

```
VideoCapture cap("videoStream");
```

and uses `cap.read()` to push into a `Mat`.

My main concern is that I use `ffenc_mpeg4` here and I believe this alters my video quality.  I tried using `x264enc` in place of `ffenc_mpeg4` but I have no output : openCV doesn't react, neither does gstreamer, and after a couple of seconds, gst-launch just stops.

Any idea what I could use instead of `ffenc_mpeg4` ? I looked for "lossless codec" on the net, but it seems I am confusing things such as codec, contains, format, compression and encoding ; so any help would be (greatly) appreciated !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: did you by chance solve this issue ?

Comment: Yes I did. Sort of. First of all: forget about gstreamer0.10 and switch to gstreamer1.0. 0.10 is seriously deprecated. Then I did used x264 decoder / encoder.