# How to create gstreamer pipe in python and open in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

Hi I want to create the following pipe in python.

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 !  application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264,payload=96 !  rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 !  autovideosink`

I have tried the following

```
 pipeline = gst.Pipeline("test-pipeline")
 source =  "udp://@127.0.0.1:5000" 
 rtph264pay= gst.element_factory_make("rtph264pay", "rtph264pay") 
 x264enc= gst.element_factory_make("x264enc", "x264enc")
 pipeline.add(source,rtph264pay,x264enc)  
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline);        
 cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('H', '2', '6', '4'));        
 cap.set(3,640)
 cap.set(4,340)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I read the following questions :
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192871/playing-rtsp-with-python-gstreamer)

Answer (score 0):

It seems [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24283114/3327912) is similar.
And are you sure VideoCapture function supports direct gst PIPE?
I only used videoN device (loop-back or direct).